# Inserting using AddWithValue - throws an error?

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, database, vb.net

**Hi. the first code snippet inserts textbox values into database and it works well:**

```vb
    Public Sub InsertintoTable(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
        Dim adp As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [users_tbl] (usr_username,usr_password) values ('" & username & "','" & password & "')", con)
        adp.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Sub
```

**Instead, I would like to use AddWithValue, so i try this:**

```asp
    Public Sub InsertintoTable(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As String)
        Using adp As New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO [users_tbl] (usr_username, usr_password) values (@username, @password)", con)
            adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_username", username)
            adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_password", password)
            adp.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
    End Sub
```

**but unfortunately it throws an Error:**

```js
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Must declare the scalar variable "@username".
```

---

Why the error? might my `AddWithValue` snippet be wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Not used the method myself, but looks like your should have `AddWithValue("@username", username)` instead of `"@user_username"`

Comment: Thank you that's right. Anyway i don't know why there are a lot of parameters to AddWithValue, this makes things complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter names are different, this works:

```
adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password)
```

or change the sql from

```
INSERT INTO [users_tbl] (usr_username, usr_password) values (@username, @password)
```

to

```
INSERT INTO [users_tbl] (usr_username, usr_password) values (@usr_username, @usr_password)
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, that was helpful. I'm not sure which answer should i set as accepted, i wish i could set both.

Answer (score 4):

Your query is expecting these two variables:

```
@username, @password
```

But you pass it variables of a different name:

```
adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_username", username)
adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@usr_password", password)
```

The parameter names need to match.  Something like this:

```
adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)
adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password)
```

Comment: Thank you David, that was helpful. I'm not sure which answer should i set as accepted, i wish i could set both.